# TFS error - TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred

Tags: tfs

Okay, nothing had changed in TFS (at least to my knowledge and I'm the administrator!).

I received the error "TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred", when clicking on a previous sprint in the backlog.  A colleague also received the same error when trying to move an item within an iteration of the current backlog.

Navigating to each team, opening the 'Configure work areas...' menu and doing nothing more, appeared to correct the error (or was it a coincidence?).

Has anyone got a clear and definitive answer as to why the error occurred?  More importantly, how to correct it?  Surely there's more to my simply browsing between the teams.

Comment: Old post is old, and I'm guessing you fixed this, but for the purposes of the record... We just had the same error message in our environment (on-premise), and the root-cause was that the C: drive on the TFS server was full. We saw the TF400898 error when inserting images into stories/bugs, and also when trying to commit a change set.

Answer (score 4):

This error can also arise, if the TFS server is out of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a clear and definitive answer, as the error is not able to be reproduced on others/my environment.

But there are some tips for you to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Make sure your TFS2012 has upgraded to latest edition.
2. Check [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/03/19/how-to-fix-tf400898-an-internal-error-occurred-on-your-kanban-board-in-tfs-2012-update-2/) to see whether you have provisioning logic issue.
3. Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache_v11.0
4. Check Event Log in Event Viewer to see whether there is useful information.

Answer (score 0):

```
TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerShortCircuitException
```

This error started occurring for us when our database machine went down unexpectedly. When accessing the TFS/ADS Admin Console it started throwing errors about cannot connect to the configured database. Restarting the database and verifying its health resolved this issue for us.